# swift IBAction on button with two classes

Tags: ios, swift, button, uiviewcontroller, unrecognized-selector

I wonder if I can trigger an action with a button created in an another class.

I explain:

I have two classes, the view controller, and a class used to create a view.

In the view controller, I call a method located in the second class to create a custom view. Then I add the custom view to the main view (see code below). 
The custom view displays a button and I don't know how I can use my button because the method created as a target is not found when I run my app.

Code viewController:

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    var popupViewBeforeOrderCoupon:UIView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        popupViewBeforeOrderCoupon = CustomView.createPopupViewWithList()
        self.view.addSubview(popupViewBeforeOrderCoupon!)        
    }

    func cancelView(sender: UIButton!) {
        var alertView = UIAlertView();
        alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK");
        alertView.title = "Alert";
        alertView.message = "Button Pressed!!!";
        alertView.show();
    }

}
```

and the second class CustomView:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class CustomView {

    init () {

    }

    static func createPopupViewWithList() -> UIView? {
        var dynamicView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(100, 200, 200, 100))
        dynamicView.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        dynamicView.alpha = 1
        dynamicView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        dynamicView.layer.borderWidth = 2

        let button = UIButton();
        button.setTitle("Add", forState: .Normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: .Normal)
        button.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 50)
        dynamicView.addSubview(button)

        button.addTarget(self, action: "cancelView:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

        return dynamicView
    }

    func cancelView(sender: UIButton!) {
        var alertView = UIAlertView();
        alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK");
        alertView.title = "Alert";
        alertView.message = "Button Pressed!!!";
        alertView.show();
    }
}
```

I want my button created in `customView` to call the method `cancelView` when I press it but I don't manage to do it.

Here's the error I get :

> NSForwarding: warning: object 0x523c8 of class 'Myproject.CustomView' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
>   Unrecognized selector +[Myproject.CustomView cancelView:]

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your createPopupViewWithList to accept 1 argument of UIViewController and then set button's target to it.

Code:

```
static func createPopupViewWithList(controller: UIViewController) -> UIView? {
    var dynamicView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(100, 200, 200, 100))
    dynamicView.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
    dynamicView.alpha = 1
    dynamicView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    dynamicView.layer.borderWidth = 2

    let button = UIButton();
    button.setTitle("Add", forState: .Normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: .Normal)
    button.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 50)
    dynamicView.addSubview(button)

    // set your controller here
    button.addTarget(controller, action: "cancelView:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    return dynamicView
}
```

Then call your function from FirstViewController:

```
popupViewBeforeOrderCoupon = CustomView.createPopupViewWithList(self)
```

Comment: Thank you it works great !! Just a question, is this a good way to do it or from the beginning i have everything wrong ? but your solution works for me

Comment: I can't tell you is this a good way or not because I am a newbie too. I just can tell you how to solve your problem. So if it works, why not to use it? Maybe someone else can tell you what is better). Don't forget to accept it as an answer if you can).

Comment: Thank you and happy coding!)